Chrome extension: Context offscreen.html Stack Trace offscreen.html:0 (anonymous function)
I am following the Use Offscreen Documents workflow, to implement signInWithPopup. Sometimes after a successful login or after back to successful and a failed login I receive this message in the chrome extension errors. The offscreen.html file is also no longer showing up, I usually have to remove and unload the extension again to make it work.
I tried, signing in and it worked, then out after like 10 seconds and the popup no longer shown up and received the message offscreen.html is not available

The error message isn't telling anything. Open devtools for the offscreen document in chrome://extensions page for your extension and look at the error stack there.

@woxxom ah, thank you. In the offscreen.html other than the "Third party cookies will be blocked", I am getting "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'compute-pressure'", I'm wondering if it something to do with my manifest file
